# Simple Change to Cylinder

Tags: edit-mode

I need to make a simple change to a cylinder in Blender.

Desired effect: the cylinder widens at both ends. The middle remains constant size.

So, when look at cylinder, from middle to top, can see that it widens; from middle to bottom, can see that it widens.

Top and bottom are of equal width. Middle width is smaller than top or bottom of cylinder.

The change in width from middle to either end of cylinder is not abrupt: it's gradual.

This simple picture to illustrates my goal.

[image]

Comment: create an edge at its middle and bevel?

Comment: Close. Not quite. I like the suggestion. But we're not there yet.

Comment: I'd usually create an edge loop with CTRL-R and increase the number of loops with the scroll wheel then turn on Proportional editing with 'O', select just the middle loop, and scale it down again using the scroll wheel until you get the curvature you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought moonboots will write the answer, but since he didn't... Create a cylinder with default settings, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> go to *Edit Mode*, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> add a single horizontal loop cut, <kbd>S</kbd> scale it down, <kbd>N</kbd> open *Number Panel* and assign bevel weight to the loop, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> go to *Object Mode*, add the bevel modifier and set it to bevel by weight:

[image]